# How to call a method in .Net DLL in a Java program

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jni4net

I was trying to use a .NET DLL from Java code, the *tsMemberFunctions.DLL* is loaded successfully, but the code fails to call the actual function.

See the snippet below:

```
public class tsMemberFunctions {  
    public native void GetMemberJSONSample();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("tsMemberFunctions");
        System.out.println("Loaded");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new tsMemberFunctions().GetMemberJSONSample();

    }
}
```

On executing above method I am getting below error:

```
Loaded
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tsMemberFunctions.GetMemberJSONSample()V
    at tsMemberFunctions.GetMemberJSONSample(Native Method)
    at tsMemberFunctions.main(tsMemberFunctions.java:12)
```

Can someone please tell me if I missed anything or anything is incorrect in the code or suggest better alternative for this use case. TIA.

Comment: Why do you need a native library to get JSON?  I'd figure out how to make an HTTP call and get it that way.  Native code is not the most portable thing you can choose.

Comment: Hi, you could ignore the function name, the main aim of this snippet is to call a method from dll file which is not happening with the current code.

Comment: My concern still stands.  You should think of another way.  Read this if you must: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful with the names and exports.

Let's say you have this super simple lib

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo001_HelloWorld_displayMessage

(JNIEnv* env, jclass obj) {

    printf("Hello world!\n");

}
```

You have to make sure to build your `DLL` for proper architecture (it will depend on Java version you have - 32/64 bit).

Let's say you have `x64 DLL` and `x64 JDK`, you can call your lib like this

```
package recipeNo001;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static native void displayMessage();

    static {
        System.load("C:\\Users\\your_name\\Source\\Repos\\HelloWorld\\x64\\Debug\\HelloWorld.dll");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      HelloWorld.displayMessage();
    }
}
```

In your case, I bet you don't have `extern "C"` in your code - this is why your symbol can't be found by JVM.

When it comes to tools, I suggest Visual Studio 2019 (when it comes to creating DLL) and IntelliJ for Java code.

You can find lots of samples here:   http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/ and here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook

Comment: OP used the term ".NET DLL" which could mean they're using a managed C++ or C# DLL that depends on the .NET framework. I'm not sure that they even have an `extern "C"` interface.

Comment: If this is the case (you have a managed DLL), it will be necessary to use C/C++ native bridge. Inside the bridge, you will have to load .Net DLL and run the code from the lib.